# how to query all the permissions a user have in flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am confused how to get all the permissions a user is having.
I have 4 model as below.(User, Role , role_permission ( as association table ),Permission )

```
class User(db.Model , UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True , autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id') , nullable = False )
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.name}',{self.email}', '{self.company}' , '{self.country}' , '{self.password}' , '{self.role_id}')"

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    user = db.relationship('User' ,uselist=False)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True ,autoincrement=True)
    role_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False , unique=True)

    _add_permission = db.relationship('Permission' , secondary=lambda:role_permission , backref= db.backref('permission', lazy = 'dynamic') , lazy = 'dynamic' )
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ROle('{self.id}',{self.role_name}')"

role_permission = db.Table('Role_Permission', 
    db.Column('id',db.Integer, primary_key=True , autoincrement=True),
    db.Column('roleName' , db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id') , nullable = False),
    db.Column('permissionName' , db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('permission.id') , nullable = False)
)

class Permission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'permission'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True , autoincrement=True)
    permission_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False , unique=True)

    _add_role = db.relationship('Role' , secondary=lambda:role_permission , backref= db.backref('role', lazy = 'dynamic') , lazy = 'dynamic')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Permission('{self.permission_name}')"
```

> suppose it is my user
> user = User ( ...., role-id = 1)   // he is admin

```
Role:
id   role_name
1    admin
2    guest

role_permision
role_id     permission_id
1               1   ( he can add)
1               2  ( he can read)

permisison
1 ----> add
2----->read
3----->view
```

> as you can see user1 is admin, being admin he can add and read.
> How can I get this result using sqlalchemy.? **how to know which user is having which role and which permissions.**

since I am new to this area and want to learn and explore your help is much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

All right, so suppose you have a user ID. You can do this in a Python focussed way, or in a SQL-focussed way.

**In python,** you need to add [`relationship`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html) attributes so that a `user` has access to `role` as well as `role_id`. In this example, add `role = db.relationship('Role', backref='users')` to the `User` model. Secondly, why do you call the relationships `_add_*`? I'd just remove that.

To get the `User` object, you can use `user = User.query.get(1)`, then `role = user.role` to get an instance of `Role`. Now, `permissions = role.permissions` and you're done. This is easy, but takes a few queries - you just don't notice it.

```py
user = User.query.get(1)
role = user.role
permissions = role.permissions
```

**In SQL**, you can also create a query to get it all at once:

```sql
SELECT permission_id
FROM role_permission
-- you can even remove this line and join `user and role_permission` directly
JOIN role ON role.id = role_id
JOIN user ON user.role_id = role.id
WHERE user.id = 1;
```

Which in SQLAlchemy would become

```py
permission_ids = db.session\
  .query(Permission.id)\
  .join(Role)\
  .join(User)\
  .filter(User.id == 1)\
  .all()
```

Here, SQLAlchemy already knows how the tables should be joined because of the `backref` and `secondary` attributes you placed in the model definition!